# Command to restore crashed shell on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

When on old versions of Windows the shell (taskbar and desktop) crashed, you could go to the task manager and run `explorer.exe`. That doesn't work in Windows 8 anymore (at least not in 8.1 Update 1, which I'm using), since explorer.exe just opens an explorer window.

It seems that in Windows 8, the shell has moved to a different process. Right now, I've accidentally managed to kill my taskbar and desktop, but also don't have Metro - Win+Tab does nothing, hot corners and charms are gone, and Alt+Tab shows the windows XP task switcher. Interestingly, per-monitor DPI is also borked, and windows dont switch scaling when I move them to a different screen. DWM/Aero is still working, and Aero snap is also working. (Fascinating how a bug lets you glimpse into the architecture of the UI...)

So, what is the command that brings back Metro and the taskbar (without rebooting)? I *definitely* know there is one, since I've been in this situation before and figured it out, but I forgot it again.